# Delayed Job Queue, Priority, Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have around 10 queues in my code, each having separate workers. All have default priorities - 1.

Currently, the requests coming from user (UI) & rake tasks are going in same queue. Suppose, request coming for fetching data from user & rake task are going in same queue with priority 1 & both are executing one by one depends on request time.

But I want to run the request from user first & then the rake task. How can I manage this ?

I also want to understand if I create a separate queue for rake task & give it low priority, then how it will work. Will it run along with another queues or wait for them to execute first?

```
Delayed::Worker.queue_attributes = {
  high_priority: { priority: -10 },
  low_priority: { priority: 10 }
}
```

Comment: could you also share the code where the job is enqueued?

Answer (score 0):

This article could help you further - it also has coding examples that you can use to try with your own code:
https://phil.tech/2016/tips-on-sidekiq-queues/

Basically, if you want to run the request from users first, you should make a queue for them and assign it a higher priority. No need to assign -10, just start from 0 and work your way up.

But also keep in mind that you should not have more than a handful queues, so it might make sense to bundle different priorities together:

> I don't recommend having more than a handful of queues. Lots of queues makes for a more complex system and Sidekiq Pro cannot reliably handle multiple queues without polling. M Sidekiq Pro processes polling N queues means O(M*N) operations per second slamming Redis.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues

Finally, if one part of your code has to run before another, you could also enqueue the rake task from the job that handles the user requests.

Comment: But this is for sidekiq-queues, I am looking for delayed job library

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to run the request from user first & then the rake task.
> How can I manage this ?

Recommend change `Delayed::Worker.default_priority` to a positive number, for example: 5, then define a `priority` method in the user workers return a lower number

```
class UserRequestJob < ApplicationJob
  def priority
    1 # lower numbers run first
  end
  ...
end
```

> I also want to understand if I create a separate queue for rake task &
> give it low priority, then how it will work. Will it run along with
> another queues or wait for them to execute first?

It will run higher priority jobs first, and then lower priority jobs, in fact queue name doesn't matter after a job is enqueued, unless you have [dedicated workers](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs), when you define queues with priority:

```
Delayed::Worker.queue_attributes = {
  high_priority: { priority: -10 },
  low_priority: { priority: 10 }
}
```

and then you enqueue a job to a queue, delayed_job will get the priority by queue name, as you can see in [job_preparer.rb](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/backend/job_preparer.rb#L33)

References:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#named-queues